# UIImageView cannot autosizing in UITableiViewCell with AutoLayout

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

the debug info list belows:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170c5d50 V:[UIImageView:0x170c5ca0(87)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170c5f70 UIImageView:0x170c5b60.top == UIImageView:0x170c5900.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170c6000 UIImageView:0x170c5ca0.top == UIImageView:0x170c5b60.top + 10>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170c6030 V:[UIImageView:0x170c5ca0]-(18)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x170c5400 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170c60f0 V:|-(15)-[UIImageView:0x170c5900]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x170c5400 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x170c6bd0 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x170c5400(131)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170c5d50 V:[UIImageView:0x170c5ca0(87)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I am doing a chat function. the outer ImageView is the background,the inner is a chat image send by user. The Inner is pinned to outer from the four side and to the contentView at bottom for autosizing the cell.  At the same time ,setting its width and height constraints and the innner imageview's mode is aspectfit in storyboard.  This is the conditions:

My problem is the debug log said the height cannot applyed, why ? The Height of UIImageView cannot be modified in Autolayout ?   Thanks a lot, apprecating your apply.

Comment: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` this means you have set a constraint twice somewhere either in code or in the IB. Would you mind showing a screenshot of the Storyboard?

Comment: i wanna post a image. But i have not enough reputations on stackoverflow. sorroy

Comment: Just post the link and I will turn it into an image for you. Tell me when you edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Ok. this is the link.  [this first is the cell,](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rSEvg.png) ,[the second is the inner image of chat content](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RdmI9.png)

Comment: Okay, accept my edit to display these images in your post.

Comment: where to accpet ? sorry,i cant find it

Comment: By the way, The application can run normally after i disable the objc_exception_throw symbol breakpoint. But the debugg info in the question still exists.  is it OK?